# had been using vs has been using

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

I want to say my friend was using a software since five years ago and he's still using the software, now which term is right :

- My friend `has been using` a software for five years.
- My friend `had been using` a software for five years.

or both are incorrect?

Comment: Both are ok. Context will decide which fits better.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it

Comment: @DamkerngT.- Thanks, it should be a good page(chapter maybe) specially presented by Stony B.

Comment: "since five years ago" is awkward. See for instance *[Proper usage of “since” and “from” with regard to duration of time](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/proper-usage-of-since-and-from-with-regard-to-duration-of-time/1399#1399)* and *[“I've been working here since two months ago”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95062)*. Is should be "for the past five years" or "for five years".

Comment: Also "a software" sounds strange". A specific software "the software" or "a particular software" would be OK. But "a software" is non-specific, so it is more natural to just say "software" if that is your intended meaning.

Answer (score 4):

If the action has not finished, the correct choice is *has been using*. The first sentence is okay.

You can make that first sentence more idiomatic by using ‘for’ instead of ‘since’: “My friend has been using the software *for five years*”, or “My friend has been using the software *for the last five years*.”

Comment: So I guess the other is correct if the action is finished for example today, I mean from 5 years ago up to today, right?

Comment: The case of “finishing today” is tricky. You say “had been using” for something that was the case in the past: “My friend had been using software X for five years when he decided [last year, or last month] to switch to software Y.” Today, can it be really clear that your friend won’t use the software again?

Comment: does it genuinely sound strange to a native speaker if someone mix 'has been' and 'had been' up in a relaxed conversation (as opposed to the commodity and frequency of a kind of conversation where it would irritate an academic level sensitivity toward purity)?

Comment: @n611x007: whether something's past-tense *can* be very important (*"Oh, you like Masa?  He had been married for 5 years."* vs. *"... He has been married for five years"*), but isn't always particularly important (*"She has|had been using Dove body wash for 5 years - you could ask her if it's worth buying"* - either way she'll have an opinion on the product).